# What is physically pushing on the piezoelectric disk?

Tags: forces, visible-light, photons, piezoelectric

When I taped a piezoelectric disk to a piece of plate glass I was surprised that a simple blue laser pointer moved the disk enough to produce almost a 1/10th of a volt[image] Something physically hit the piezoelectric disk that caused it to move enough to generate .09 volts. I know photons are at the heart of this, but what actual took place at the surface of the piezoelectric disk. I duplicated the force necessary on the piezo to get the same voltage. It took a good puff of air to do it, equivalent to a small cough

Comment: Not an answer for you question, but I cringe a little that you're looking at a $.09~\rm V$ signal on the $20~\rm V$ scale. That's what the $200~\rm mV$ scale is for. ;)

Comment: I could use a lesson on the scale settings. Why do they use 200's and not 100's. When I put it up on the 200m setting it jumps around a lot.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the heat produced by the photons. The photons exert some pressure directly, but not much.

Comment: here is a measurement of the momentum of light  http://www.gamma.nbi.dk/Galleri/gamma152/christopherrjacobsen.pdf

Comment: It is most likely due to the heating of air by the laser. With that said if you do happen to have a vacuum chamber this method seems promising to measure force exerted by photons.

Comment: @Lambda I would bet the 2's are historical. I don't know off the top of my head, though. You generally want to use the smallest scale possible for better measurement. It seems pretty likely in this case that the voltage really is jumping around. Might be interesting to look at it with an oscilloscope.